# Espacio en blanco en cabecera - provocado por margin-top del ul

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

**Edito**: acabo de ver que es el ul, pero, ¿no debería dejar el margen relativo al padre?

Estoy realizando algo tan sencillo como una cabecera, pero por alguna razón al introducir un margen en el `ul` produce el margen por fuera del contenedor del padre.

Código HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Código CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper .header {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("../imgs/header/header.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .header::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .2;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .header .menu {
  margin: 100px 0 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.wrapper .header .menu li {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.wrapper .header .menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: "open-sans";
}
```

Link al JSFiddle que reproduce el mismo error: https://jsfiddle.net/5gf3g58v/

Comment: El único espacio en blanco que encuentro en el fiddle en la parte de arriba está generado por el margen superior de 100px, ¿es ese espacio al que te refieres?

Comment: @Shaz Justamente acabo de verlo, pero no debería ser relativo el margen que deja el ul al header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese "fenómeno" se llama márgenes colapsadas, está definido en la especificación del [Box model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) de CSS. Hay varias formas de resolver el problema, una de las más comunes es usando padding en vez de margin en el elemento hijo:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper .header {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("../imgs/header/header.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .header::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .2;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .header .menu {
  padding: 100px 0 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.wrapper .header .menu li {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.wrapper .header .menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: "open-sans";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias, si, es la única forma que se me ocurría para arreglar. ¡Un poco molesto la verdad! Ahora cuando pueda te doy la solución correcta ;)

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacerlo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element